# rworldmaps-R- Cant make it interactive

Tags: r

My code is:

```
theCountry <- c("CAN", "DEU", "ITA","USA","GBR","FRA","JPN")
# These are the ISO3 names of the countries you'd like to plot in red

malDF <- data.frame(country = c("CAN", "DEU", "ITA","USA","GBR","FRA","JPN"),
                    SixtyFivePlus = c("16.15%", "21.12%", "22.36%", "14.64%", "18.12%", "18.94%", "26.02%"))
# malDF is a data.frame with the ISO3 country names plus a variable to
# merge to the map data

malMap <- joinCountryData2Map(malDF, joinCode = "ISO3",
                              nameJoinColumn = "country")
# This will join your malDF data.frame to the country map data

mapCountryData(malMap, nameColumnToPlot="SixtyFivePlus", catMethod = "categorical",
               missingCountryCol = gray(.8), colourPalette = c("seagreen","seagreen1","seagreen2",
"seagreen3","chartreuse","chartreuse2","chartreuse4"))

identifyCountries(dF = "malDF"
                  , nameCountryColumn = "malMap"
               , nameColumnToPlot = "SixtyFivePlus"
                  , plotSelected = FALSE
                  )
```

Its giving this error :
Error in identify.default(x = dF2[[nameX]], y = dF2[[nameY]], labels = labels,  : 
  zero-length 'labels' specified

I have no idea what to put in x and y since I am still learning R. Could someone help me make my map interactive so they give the values mentioned in the vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close but you are trying to plot `malDF` which is not a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`. Instead you should use the `malMap` object:

```
identifyCountries(dF = malMap,
                  nameCountryColumn = "country",
                  nameColumnToPlot = "SixtyFivePlus"
                  , plotSelected = TRUE
)
```

Which produces:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!